# Flatten php array and join index

Tags: php, xml, arrays, recursion

I've some arrays of data (xml) with this structure:

```
product
    name => "some name"
    images
        image => "1.jpg"
        image => "2.jpg"
        image => "3.jpg"
    description => "lorem ipsum"
    categories
        category => 3939
        category => 685
    price => 300
    importers
        importer => "importer1"
```

Some rows (for example "name") as strings or ints and some as nested items (images for example).

I need to make it flat and 1 level array and when row has some nested arrays index name of child should be joined with parent so it would look like this:

```
product
    name => "some name"
    images_image => "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg"
    description => "lorem ipsum"
    categories_category => "3939,685"
    price => 300
    importers_importer => "importer1"
```

Array can be nested deeper so sometimes more indexes needs to be joined (so propably it needs `recursion`

It seems to be simple logic but I've problems with it for longer while and cant figure it out how to make it working.

Nested arrays has 'same-type children only'. So if one of them is for example 'image' named

Even some pseudo code will be helpful for me.

Comment: Why would you do this `images_image => "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg"`?

Comment: My customer needs advanced importing panel with options of mapping fields of xml in simple words and it needs that kind of standarized structure, also it would not propably be comma-separated but with some special char, but its not point of problem.

Comment: Could you please give an example of nesting with 2 levels (or more) and what would be the result you expect?

Comment: I've just realized it will get slick then. So lets assume now we dont have mulit nested data.

Comment: I'm not sure how you store the construct 
`categories
        category => 3939
        category => 685`
in the original array.
Is it like that:
`array( 'categories' => array( 'category' => array(3939, 685) ) )` ?

Comment: Yes, it will be like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function array_flatten_recursive($in_array) {
  $out_array = array();
  foreach ($in_array as $key => $value) {
    if( is_array($value) ){
      $rec_array = array_flatten_recursive($value);
      foreach ($rec_array as $rec_key => $rec_value) {
        $out_array["{$key}_{$rec_key}"] = $rec_value;
      }
    } else {
      $out_array[$key] = $value;      
    }
  }
  return $out_array;
}
```

Demo on [eval.in](https://eval.in/33766)

Comment: That seems to flatten but not join the array, but that's the right direction

Comment: Yes, as Chen said, thats the only thing missing here. Condition of imploding it to comma separated is that there is no more nesting, so - if child array is array of strings/ints, implde it with comma.